# Count totals by year and month

Tags: mysql, date, group-by, aggregate

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id,created,action
1,'2011-01-01 04:28:21','signup'
2,'2011-01-05 04:28:21','signup'
3,'2011-02-02 04:28:21','signup'
```

How do I select and group these so the output is:

```
year,month,total
2011,1,2
2011,2,1
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created, '%Y') as 'year',
DATE_FORMAT(created, '%m') as 'month',
COUNT(id) as 'total'
FROM table_name
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created, '%Y%m')
```

Comment: This not works. The same columns must be in the group by and in the select condition, so you need to return  DATE_FORMAT(created, '%Y%m') or split the group by in two conditions

Comment: I used this to count Wordpress comments per month for an excel graph via:

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(comment_date, '%Y') as 'year',
DATE_FORMAT(comment_date, '%m') as 'month',
COUNT(comment_id) as 'total'
FROM wp_comments WHERE comment_approved = 1
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(comment_date, '%Y%m')`

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT YEAR(created) as year_val, MONTH(created) as month_val ,COUNT(*) as total
FROM testing
GROUP BY YEAR(created), MONTH(created)
```