# Query for count for no of users created based on years

Tags: mysql

I have a table with columns id, name, created_date. I need to get output like

```
Years  count_of_name_created

2010     10

2012      9
```

And so on. Right now I have done with two queries, but I need it in single query.

Answer (score 1):

TRy this ::

```
Select YEAR(logged_date), count(1)
from my_table group by YEAR(logged_date) order by count(1) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that created_date is of type DateTime you could do this:

```
SELECT YEAR(created_date) AS Year, COUNT(id) FROM userTable GROUP BY YEAR(created_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

This `MySQL` query should work

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_date, '%Y') as 'year', COUNT(id) as 'total'
FROM users
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_date, '%Y')
```

see also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166344/mysql-count-totals-by-year-and-month)

Answer (score 0):

Note that while the above answers are valid, if you have a month where nothing is created you will land up with a missing row rather than a row with a count of 0 (which makes a mess of graphs!).
You can use a table of integers (ie, one column, 10 rows with the values 0 to 9) cross joined against itself a few times to get a range of numbers, and add this as the month to a start date to get a list of months. And join that against your query to get the counts (giving you months with a count of 0 when there are no matching records).

Comment: you mean a _year_ where nothing is created.  But OP wants it in created order, not date order so shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Yes, year. Although order is not specified by the OP. True they may be happy with gaps.

Answer (score 0):

Fully according to spec:

```
Select YEAR(created_date) as Years, 
       count(name) as count_of_name_created
from <table_name> 
group by YEAR(created_date) 
order by count(name) desc;
```